# Returning array with checked properties to the DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, checkbox, filter

I am trying to set up a filter with multiple checkboxes in an Angular 1 app within a ServiceNow widget. I have the following client code:

```
$scope.model = {    }   
$scope.documentsArray = [];     
$scope.loadResults = function(){    
    $scope.c.forEach(function(x) {  
        $scope.d.forEach(function(doc) {    
            $scope.documentsArray.push(doc);                
        });
    });
};//end loadResults

$scope.loadResults();   


$scope.filteredDocs=function(obj){

//sets up an array to hold values of checked boxes
var filtersChecked = [];

//if nothing has been checked this returns the original, unfiltered array. 

for(var key in $scope.model){
  if($scope.model.key===obj) {
      filtersChecked.push(key);         
      if(filtersChecked.length == 0){
        return $scope.documentsArray;
      } 
   }
}

return $scope.documentsArray.filter(function(doc) {
    for (var filter in filtersChecked) {
        return doc.meta(filter).indexOf > -1;   
    }
});
```

And the following HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="results" ng-repeat="x in filteredDocs() | filter: kb_view_filter track by $index" ng-model="model">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" width="75%">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3>{{x.short_description}} {{x.meta}}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can see that the checked boxes are pushing to the filteredArray, but the correctly filtered result is not being pushed back to the DOM. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, it is hard to know exactly what you're trying to do without any more context than what is given, but there are a couple things that jump out at me -- one of which is your use of `indexOf` in your filter function. IndexOf is a function that takes an argument, the syntax is `[collection].indexOf([value to search for])` and it returns an integer of the index where the value was found, or -1 if it was not found. I think that may be why your filter is failing.

Comment: You are also using a `return` statement from within your `for...in` loop, so only the first element in `filtersChecked` will get evaluated for each value in `documentsArray`. Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish by the inner `for` loop inside your filter function? That way I can help come up with an alternative method.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is return the items that include the meta data tags that are checked in the HTML. The checkboxes include ng-model="model.a" and seem to be toggling true/false correctly. It's entirely possible I was going down the wrong path with the for loop placement and structure - if you have any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: I had a vague idea that was what you were trying to accomplish, but what logic are you wanting? if the check for all meta data tags pass? if one passes? Also, now that I look at the loop that is creating the `filtersChecked` array, the line `$scope.model.key === obj` will never pass, because you are asking for the property called `key`, not the property with the name that is the value of the key variable inside your loop. It should be `$scope.model[key] === obj`

Comment: Can you please post more of your code? Specifically, what `$scope.model`, `obj`, and `$scope.documentsArray` look like

Comment: I posted most of the code I have - the loadResults function pulls the entire list of documents from the server side, all of which have one or more metadata property attached. These are pushed to the documentsArray.  My intent was to create an empty object model which holds the ng-model links that go with each checkbox. Then, I made the filteredDocs function with the filteredDocs array that holds the checked meta properties. The idea was to push the documentsArray back onto the DOM filtering through the filteredDocs array, although that's obviously not working.